# Check if there are marked files in dired buffer

Tags: dired, help

How can I check, with a function, if there are marked files in a dired buffer?

**Edit.** The issue with `dired-get-marked-files` is that if the user moves the cursor on a "current file name" the function does not return `nil`.

What about `(string-match-p "^\\*" (buffer-string))`? Is it so bad?

Comment: `dired-number-of-marked-files` returns a string that is useful interactively, but you probably want to use the underlying function `dired-get-marked-files`, but you'll need to get rid of the current file name: AFAICT, if no files are marked, the file on the current line is always returned).

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: The `string-match-p` looks reasonable to me for the yes/no question. If you want the actual number, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One quick way is to just use this, since you apparently don't want to consider the file of the current line as marked if it's not:

```lisp
(dired-remember-marks (point-min) (point-max))
```

---

A more general answer is to use function `dired-get-marked-files`.  If there are marked files it returns their names as a list. But since most uses of it are to get file names, to do something with them, it also returns the name of the current line's file, if no files are marked. If you don't want that, see above or at the end of my answer.

That's the *usual* Lisp way: **return a useful non-`nil` value for "true"**. It costs nothing and is far more useful than just learning that there are some marked files.

`C-h f dired-get-marked-files`.  Here's the description from [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus):

> **`dired-get-marked-files`** is a compiled Lisp function in `dired+.el`.
>
> `(dired-get-marked-files &optional LOCALP ARG FILTER DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED ERROR-IF-NONE-P)`
>
> Return names of the marked files and directories as a list of strings.
>
> The list is in the same order as the buffer, that is, the car is the first marked file.
>
> Values returned are normally absolute file names.
>
> - Optional arg `LOCALP` as in `dired-get-filename`.
>   *Optional second argument `ARG` specifies files to use instead of marked.
>   Usually `ARG` comes from the command's prefix arg.
>
> If `ARG` is an integer, use the next `ARG` files (previous `-ARG`, if < 0).
> (1 means file on current line.  -1 means file on previous line.)
>
> If `ARG` is a cons with element 16, 64, or 256, corresponding to
> `C-u C-u`, `C-u C-u C-u`, or `C-u C-u C-u C-u`, then use all files
> in the Dired buffer, where:
>
> - 16 includes NO directories (including `.` and `..`)
> - 64 includes directories EXCEPT `.` and `..`
> - 256 includes ALL directories (including `.` and `..`)
>
> If `ARG` is otherwise non-`nil`, use the current file.
>
> Optional third argument `FILTER`, if non-`nil`, is a function to select
> some of the files: those for which `(funcall FILTER FILENAME)` is
> non-`nil`.
>
> If `DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED` is non-`nil`, then return `(t FILENAME)` instead
> of `(FILENAME)` if only one file is marked (after any filtering by
> `FILTER`).
>
> If `ERROR-IF-NONE-P` is non-`nil`, signal an error if the list of files is
> empty.  If `ERROR-IF-NONE-P` is a string then it is the error message.
>
> Note that the Dired+ version of this function differs from the vanilla
> version in these respects:
>
> - There are more possibilities for argument `ARG` (prefix argument).
> - Directories `.` and `..` can be included as marked.
> - You can use arguments `FILTER` and `DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED` together.

---

And here's the vanilla Emacs version:

> **`dired-get-marked-files`** is a byte-compiled Lisp function in `dired.el`.
>
> `(dired-get-marked-files &optional LOCALP ARG FILTER DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED ERROR)`
>
> Return the marked files’ names as list of strings.
>
> The list is in the same order as the buffer, that is, the car is the first marked file.
>
> Values returned are normally absolute file names.
>
> Optional arg `LOCALP` as in `dired-get-filename`’.
>
> Optional second argument `ARG`, if non-`nil`, specifies files near
> point instead of marked files.  It usually comes from the prefix
> argument.
>
> - If `ARG` is an integer, use the next `ARG` files.
> - If `ARG` is any other non-`nil` value, return the current file name.
> - If no files are marked, and `ARG` is `nil`, also return the current file name.
>
> Optional third argument `FILTER`, if non-`nil`, is a function to select
> some of the files--those for which `(funcall FILTER FILENAME)` is non-`nil`.
>
> If `DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED` is non-`nil`, then if we find just one marked file,
> return `(t FILENAME)` instead of `(FILENAME)`.
> Don’t use that together with `FILTER`.
>
> If `ERROR` is non-`nil`, signal an error when the list of found files is empty. `ERROR` can be a string with the error message.

---

Wrt your "evolved" question (please don't do that): here are two alternatives.

1. Just use this:

```lisp
(dired-remember-marks (point-min) (point-max))
```

`C-h f dired-remember-marks`.

2. Read the doc for `dired-get-marked-files`.  It too can give you what you want. If you want `nil` to be returned when there are no marks, rather than returning the file of the current line, just use this:

```lisp
(defun my-get-marked (localp arg filter error)
  "..."
  (let ((res  (dired-get-marked-files localp arg filter t error)))
    (if (and res  (null (cdr res)))
        nil
      res)))
```

Comment: I thought about `dired-get-marked-files`. Please look at my edited question.

Comment: @Drew: the problem with the convention of returning always something useful from `dired-get-marked-files` is the misleading function name. `dired-get-file-at-point-plus-marked-files` would be a much better name saving time of looking up what it actually does.

Comment: @Drew: what about proposing a patch to `dired` changing the behavior of `dired-get-marked-files` and extending it with `dired-get-file-at-point-plus-marked-files` instead of suggesting usage of own function?

Comment: As I wrote, there already is a function to do what you asked: `dired-remember-marks`. The point about `dired-get-marked-files` is that it's used to, yes, actually get a list of files, and a very common use case is to get the current-line file when no file is marked. `dired-do-*` commands all work that way: act on the current-line file if no numeric prefix arg is given and no files are marked. I only showed you how you can *also* use `dired-get-marked-files` to give you `nil` when no files are marked.

Comment: `dired-remember-marks` also has the advantage of returning the mark associated with each file (e.g. files marked with `D` as well as those marked with `*`).

Comment: @NickD: indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`dired-number-of-marked-files` returns a string and is most useful interactively because of that. But its implementation uses `dired-get-marked-files` which returns a list of marked files - if there *are* marked files. But it returns the `current file` (i.e. whatever your cursor is on), not `nil` if there are no marked files. To distinguish these cases, there is an optional argument `DISTINGUISH-ONE-MARKED` that modifies the output in this case: if the `current file` is marked, then `dired-get-marked-files` returns `(t FILENAME)` instead of `(FILENAME)`. All of this is from `C-h f dired-get-marked-files`.

Here's the code that calculates the number of marked files then (lifted directly from the implementation of `dired-number-of-marked-files`):

```el
(defun my/dired-number-of-marked-files ()
  (let* ((files (dired-get-marked-files nil nil nil t))
         (nmarked
          (cond ((null (cdr files))
                 0)
                ((and (= (length files) 2)
                      (eq (car files) t))
                 1)
                (t
                 (length files)))))
    nmarked))
```

That returns the integer that `dired-number-of-marked-files` uses to construct its message, so you figure out whether there are marked files with something like this:

```el
   (when (> (my/dired-number-of-marked-files) 0)
      ;; there be marked files here
      ...)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to suggest a patch to dired changing the behavior of the `dired-number-of-marked-files` providing an additional `dired-number-of-marked-plus-file-at-point` to avoid all this hassle?

Comment: @Claudio: feel free to do so.